# Buddypress Activity issue & cubepoints

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

i currently encounter a problem in the activity i was adding to each user to be displayed its cubepoint rank i have added the following

`<?php echo cp_module_ranks_getRank( bp_displayed_user_id() ); ?>`

but it dosent seem to work it seems to repeat the same rank on each user again and again it stays in level 1 also i have applied that same code.

i posted above and it works for each users profile so it displays there actual rank so its weird i will be posting an image of what i mean, thank you have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bp_displayed_user_id()` is used on a member profile page to determine the ID of the user's profile currently being shown, but it won't update when part of the loop. Depending on which type of loop you are using, you need to use one of the following methods:

For the activity loop, the function would be `bp_get_activity_user_id()` to return the ID and `bp_activity_user_id()` to echo it. For you case you would want to use:

```
<?php echo cp_module_ranks_getRank( bp_get_activity_user_id() ); ?>
```

In the case of the member loop, the function would be `bp_get_member_user_id()` to return the ID and `bp_member_user_id()` to echo it:

```
<?php echo cp_module_ranks_getRank( bp_get_member_user_id() ); ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Ill give it a go tonight, thanks once again for the help.

Comment: Hello, once again i have added the code `<?php echo cp_module_ranks_getRank( bp_member_user_id() ); ?>` but it doesn't seem to work at all? it still stays in the same rank?

Comment: On second look at your screenshot this looks like it is within an activity loop? If so you need to get the activity user id with `bp_activity_user_id()` - the function I originally entered is for the members loop.

Comment: Hey mate i just fixed the issue it was `bp_get_activity_user_id()` so now its displaying the rank correctly in the activity loop thanks for your effort and patience once again thanks mate.

Comment: Great, I updated my post above to reflect the appropriate methods. If you think it's satisfactory I would appreciate you marking it as the correct answer, thanks!